# How to manually parse a nested array from a JSON file into a nested array of a data model?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing, alamofire

I recently started learning Swift and was faced with the next problem. I need to use the Alamofire framework and implement manual data parsing from the JSON file into the data model. In this case, the JSON file has a nested array. I wrote the code, but an error message appears.

What needs to be done to perform such parsing?

This is the JSON file.

```json
["type": product, "number": 10, "offset": 0, "processingTimeMs": 4735, "products": <__NSArrayI 0x600002629e00>(
{
    id = 10026738;
    image = "https://spoonacular.com/productImages/10026738-312x231.jpg";
    imageType = jpg;
    title = "Jenos by totinos crsp n tsty pizza for 1 combo";
},
{
    id = 8215206;
    image = "https://spoonacular.com/productImages/8215206-312x231.jpg";
    imageType = jpg;
    title = "Supreme sausage, pepperoni, green, red and yellow peppers, roasted garlic & red onions brick oven crust pizza, supreme";
},
{
    id = 9822788;
    image = "https://spoonacular.com/productImages/9822788-312x231.jpg";
    imageType = jpg;
    title = "Grisinetos pizza";
},
...

)
, "totalProducts": 16410]
```

This is the data model.

```swift
struct Product: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let imageType: String
}

struct Grocery: Decodable {
    let products: [Product]
    let totalProducts: Int
    let type: String
    let offset: Int
    let number: Int
}
```

This is the function I wrote

```swift
private func fetchProducts() {
    AF.request(groceryLink)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { dataResponse in
        switch dataResponse.result {
        case .success(let value):
            guard let groceryDetails = value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            
            var products: [Product] = []
            
            for productDetails in groceryDetails["products"] {
                let product = Product(
                    id: productDetails["id"] as? Int ?? 0,
                    title: productDetails["title"] as? String ?? "",
                    imageType: productDetails["imageType"] as? String ?? ""
                )
                products.append(product)
            }

            let grocery = Grocery(products: products,
                                  totalProducts: groceryDetails["totalProducts"] as? Int ?? 0,
                                  type: groceryDetails["type"] as? String ?? "",
                                  offset: groceryDetails["offset"] as? Int ?? 0,
                                  number: groceryDetails["number"] as? Int ?? 0)
            
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show the full error message you get, and on which line of the code. Note the data you show is not JSON. Show some real sample.

Comment: I suggest you use quicktype.io to generate a Codable model from your JSON and use `responeDecodable` rather than trying to decode JSON yourself.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine The sample shown is `groceryDetails`, a `[String: Any]` result from decode from JSONSerialization using a mix of Swift Dictionary (since at top level it's cast as such) and OpenStepFormat of NSArray and NSDictionary, since that's the conversion of the items. It was indeed a JSON since the serialization worked, but indeed, it's not always clear what's the value types, so I'd also suggest to show the raw JSON.

Comment: @Jon Shier I have already used quicktype.io to create the model. And the second point is that this is aт asignment where it is necessary to implement exactly manual parsing.

Comment: @Larme Where can I find the raw JASON data ?

Comment: To see the json data, add this
 `if let data = dataResponse.data {
     print("---> json: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject)")
 }`, before `switch dataResponse.result {...`.
 Note `.responseJSON` will be deprecated, use `responseDecodable`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this task.

In the first line of the loop, it was necessary to cast the received data to an array of dictionaries [[String: Any]]

The fixed code is here:

```
private func fetchProducts() {
    AF.request(groceryLink)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { dataResponse in
        switch dataResponse.result {
        case .success(let value):
            guard let groceryDetails = value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            
            var products: [Product] = []
            
            for productDetails in groceryDetails["products"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? [] {
                let product = Product(
                    id: productDetails["id"] as? Int ?? 0,
                    title: productDetails["title"] as? String ?? "",
                    imageType: productDetails["imageType"] as? String ?? ""
                )
                products.append(product)
            }

            let grocery = Grocery(products: products,
                                  totalProducts: groceryDetails["totalProducts"] as? Int ?? 0,
                                  type: groceryDetails["type"] as? String ?? "",
                                  offset: groceryDetails["offset"] as? Int ?? 0,
                                  number: groceryDetails["number"] as? Int ?? 0)
            
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```